# Can not create Scratch org

Tags: salesforcedx, error, sfdx-error, force-org-create

I have an issue when invoke this line in terminal

`sfdx force:org:create edition=Developer -a MyScratchOrg -s -v devHub`

or this one

`sfdx force:org:create -f config/enterprise-scratch-def.json -a MyScratchOrg` .

The answer is

`ERROR running force:org:create:  Parse error in file unknown on line 1`.

What does it mean?

And how can I resove it?

**(sfdx updated to last version, devhub was authorized)**

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that there's an issue in one of your project CLI config files?

I suggest trying the following:

1. check `config/enterprise-scratch-def.json` file for parsing errors
2. delete the `.sf` and `.sfdx` directories at the root of your project dir

Comment: Thanks! But your suggestion does not work: i've deleted .sf and .sfdx folders, and have checked `enterprise-scratch-def.json` file - there was no mistakes. More ideas?

Comment: Also check `sfdx-project.json` for errors maybe?

Comment: Thanks! It was checked, without errors

Comment: I created scratch org a month ago without any problems

Comment: Try removing CLI plugins if any (run `sfdx plugins to list them)? If all of this doesn't work, I'm afraid that you'll have to reinstall the CLI.

Comment: I've removed plugins, but to my regret I had to reinstall Salesforce CLI 5 hours ago. But now I can use `force:org:create` command! Thank you, @POZ!

Comment: Sorry to hear that it was such a pain but I'm glad that you were able to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, if you check your SFDX-Cli installation folder at: `/Users/yourName/.sf/sf.json`
`/Users/yourName/.sfdx/sfdx-config.json`
one of those json files are corrupted, in my case it had an extra curly brace "}" in the end of file.
If you open it on VSCode you will easily find it.

Comment: Rod, thanks! In my case there was not mistakes in these files. I've checked. But my `alias.json` file was broken, that'ss true. So I had to return all my orgs back.